# How to put generator expressions as input to Python's join method?

Tags: python

How do I put several generator expressions as input to Python's `join` method? I tried the following which don't work. Is there a difference when using Python 2.x and 3.x?  My exact version is Python 2.7.12.

```
def productList(self, obj):
    return ", ".join([w.name for w in obj.someProducts.all()],[w.code 
                      for  w in obj.someProducts.all()])
```

and without the `[]`

```
    def productList(self, obj):
        return ", ".join(w.name for w in obj.someProducts.all(),w.code 
                         for  w in obj.someProducts.all())
```

input:

```
Product table
    Name:  Char;
    Code:  Char;
```

output:

```
name1code1, name2code2
```

Comment: What do you want your result to be? There should be only one generator expression - and it needs to generate strings. Give us some input/output.

Comment: You've duplicated the list-comprehension or generator expression in each of your `join` calls. Do you really want all the names twice?

Comment: sorry I edited my question I need to display name and code for the product.

Comment: How do you want the name and code to be combined? Do you want all the names, then all the codes, or do you want the name and code of each product paired up together?

Comment: Don't you want something like `", ".join((w.name+': '+w.product) for w in obj.someProducts.all())` ?

Comment: which is more Pythonic Bahroms' or Duans' code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display name and code, you just need to combine them, you don't need two generators.

```
', '.join(w.name + ':' + w.code for w in obj.someProducts.all())
```

Or string formatting:

```
', '.join('{name}: {code}'.format(name=w.name, code=w.code) for w in obj.someProducts.all())
```

Or another join (not recommended, unless you can give it a generator - creating another list is a waste, but this demonstrates how you can nest joins)

```
', '.join(':'.join([w.name, w.code]) for w in obj.someProducts.all())
```

On a side note, Python 3.6 introduces [Literal String Interpolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), which means you should be able to do something like this (I'll test this at home, since I don't have 3.6 at work; could someone verify this actually works. Let me know if it doesn't, I'll remove it):

```
', '.join(f'{w.name}: {w.code}' for w in obj.someProducts.all())
```

Comment: I'd suggest `str.format` as a much more natural way of combining the two attributes, rather than an extra `join` call.

Answer (score 2):

Give it a try:

```
', '.join('{}{}'.format(w.name, w.code) for w in obj.someProducts.all())
```

I just made the w.name and w.code one string, that way you don't need 2 lists. Change the format as you wish.